# Ubuntu Desktop certified hardware for Lenovo Laptop "G50-70 Intel Core i3 4010U"

Tags: system-installation, lenovo, hardware-certification

I have bought a Lenovo Laptop "G50-70 Intel Core i3 4010U" with pre-installed Windows 8.

I would like to install Linux but I can't find the software for my laptop [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/make/Lenovo/?category=Laptop), which one is the most compatible with it.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what your problem is. I am assuming you are asking if Ubuntu can be installed on your laptop, not if there is Linux software to run on it.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that if you download Ubuntu and install it on the laptop that it will run just fine.  If you're unsure about dual booting it along with Windows, I would highly recommend installing it as a virtual machine.  [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) is free and easy to install.  You can then create an Ubuntu virtual machine without worry about "breaking" your laptop or Windows.

Comment: Since very new computer you will need the newest 64 bit version of Ubuntu or one of its flavors (different desktops). Should be standard UEFI dual boot. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI AND: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system (Comment was not intended for answer but OP).